# sum column values considering entry in other column

Tags: linux, bash

I've got a file in which are reported some information. I'd like to sum values in column $6 considering the relative value in column $5. In detail, If value in column 5 are >= -2.0 I should consider relative value in column 6, otherwise I don't included it in the sum.

input.txt

```
2931,401,-0.3,C,-0.5,0.1,-2,C
2935,404,-0.2,S,-3.0,0.5,4,O
2940,414,1.3,C,-0.7,,,
2947,509,2.0,N,-2.0,5,-0.4,C
```

expected_output.txt -> should contains the sum of column $6 rows 1 (0.1) and 4(5) (if column 6 in line 3 was not empty it had to be consider in the sum)

```
5.1
```

I'm trying to use `awk` but I don't find the right way to do that. Could someone suggested a way please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, '($5>=-2){s+=$6}END{print s}' input.txt
```

- `-F,` tells awk that fields are separated by commas;
- the `($5>=-2)` is the condition, if it's true, `$6` is added to `s`;
- the `s` is printed at the end. If there's a possibility to have nothing to sum, you might need to print `s?s:0` or initialise `s` to 0 (`BEGIN{s=0}`).